# Multiply a float with a double

Tags: c#

I try to do a very simple thing, just multiply two numbers a float and a double.
I get the message can't convert a double to float... Thank you

```
float tax = 0f;
tax = 0.14 * 26818;
```

Comment: You're not asking a question. And of course you cannot store a double in a float.

Comment: So what are the possibilities?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you're multiplying a double and an *integer,* then trying to shoehorn the resulting double into a float.

Floats have less precision and range than doubles so you are required to *explicitly* cast to indicate to the compiler you know what you're doing :-)

So, you can either do:

```
tax = (float)(0.14 * 26818);
```

or (if you are using literals) just work with floats from the start:

```
tax = 0.14f * 26818;
```

Answer (score 0):

As [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/float) said:

> Literals By default, a real numeric literal on the right side of the
>   assignment operator is treated as double. Therefore, to initialize a
>   float variable, use the suffix f or F
>
> If you do not use the suffix in the previous declaration, you will get
>   a compilation error because you are trying to store a double value
>   into a float variable.

So in order for your expression to work, add a suffix.

```
tax = 0.14f * 26818;
```

[image]