# Multiplying float with double overflow in C++

Tags: c++, floating-point, truncate

I am a bit confused of the point of having this warning: 
Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '*' on a 4byte value and then casting the result to a 8byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling '*' operator to avoid overflow.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::ios_base;

int main() {
    cout.setf(ios_base::fixed, ios_base::floatfield);
    double mints = 10.0 / 3.0;
    const float c_MILLION = 1e6;
    cout << "\n10 million mints: " << 10 * c_MILLION * mints;

    cin.get();
}
```

According to my understanding when we multiply a float value with a double value we are basicaly multiplying a 4byte value to an 8byte value and it we will hence, lose some precision according to the links that I have read:

- [Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'float'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19671667/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-double-to-float)
- [Multiply a float with a double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46065150/multiply-a-float-with-a-double)

[http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/DE18T05o/#:~:text=Overflow%20is%20a%20phenomenon%20where,be%20larger%20than%20the%20range](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/DE18T05o/#:%7E:text=Overflow%20is%20a%20phenomenon%20where,be%20larger%20than%20the%20range)

However, when I do output this, I get a double value
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOQzm.png

If that is the case, why does it bother to warn me to cast c_MILLION to double value if it is automatically changing it to a double result? It cant convert an 8byte value to a 4byte value anyways. So, why does it bother to warn the programmers when it is already saving us from this trouble? 
 Or can it convert an 8byte value to a 4byte value as well. If so, how does it determine what type to print? This is a question that I cannot find the answer to from the links I read. 
If it automatically converting the result to 8byte value, what is the point of displaying this warning?
Here is the warning: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2szy.png 
 
**Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning C26451  Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '*' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '*' to avoid overflow (io.2)**

The problem was that I was multiplying an `int` value with a `double` value. But still the warning should not exist when it automatically converts the multiplication of an `int` to `double` to a `double` value.

Comment: What compiler are you using?  I'm not able to get this warning.  AFAICT, your code is fine.

Comment: _"...why does it bother to warn me..."_ what warnings - live - https://godbolt.org/z/joxG6K

Comment: I am using g++ compiler and Visual Studio 2019 IDE. I get this warning
Arithmetic Overflow: Using operator * on a 4byte value and then casting the result to 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling the operator * to avoid overflow.

Comment: I do not know the reason that this question was downvoted for, atleast give me a reason as to why this question has been downvoted?

Comment: @RichardCritten I have uploaded the image of the warning.

Comment: @ProgrammingRage Don't use images to copy text. Copy the text as text.

Comment: @eerorika Okay!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is because of this multiplication: `10 * c_MILLION`. There can be some values of `c_MILLION` where some precision is lost that would not have been lost if `c_MILLION` was first converted to a `double`. Since the result of this multiplication is converted to `double`, a mistaken programmer might assume that no precision was lost beyond what might be expected if the operands were `double` in the first place. Hence the warning.

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  If `c_MILLION` was a double, the same argument would apply.

Comment: @NathanOliver Only if it was later converted to a more precise type than `double`.

Comment: It still results in a ```double``` value so no precision is lost.

Comment: @ProgrammingRage multipying an `int` with `float` does **not** result in a `double`. This sort of misunderstanding is probably the reason for why the warning exists.

Comment: @NathanOliver: The compiler is saying “Hey, you are doing this arithmetic in a four-byte bucket and then putting it in an eight-byte bucket. You might get a better result starting with an eight-byte bucket in the first place.” If `c_MILLION` were a `double`, you would already be in an eight-byte bucket; there would be no opportunity to widen the earlier operation to the later size, so there is no corresponding warning.

Comment: @eerorika Oh yea... when I changed it to 10.0, the warning is gone.

Comment: @eerorika Even then, converting an int to double still works! It gives a double value back!

Comment: @eerorika Still the question remains, what is the point of this warning when I am multiplying an int with a double, if it is automatically converting it to a double?

Comment: @ProgrammingRage `c_MILLION` is not a double.

Comment: @eerorika even if it is a float, it should not send any warning because, this code does not generate any warning:
```#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::ios_base;

int main() {
 cout.setf(ios_base::fixed, ios_base::floatfield);
 float x = 2.3f;
 int y = 4;
 cout << x * y << '\n';

 cin.get();
}```

Comment: @ProgrammingRage You aren't converting the result of that multiplication to `double`, as such why would you have any expectation of having precision of a double? The diagnostic assumes that you wouldn't make such assumption, and as such there is no need to warn about such mistaken assumption.

Comment: @ProgrammingRage: The compiler is apparently not warning if you multiply an `int` by a `float` or an `int` by a `double` or a `float` by a double or an `int` by a `double` and then by a `double`. The reason it is warning with `int` times `float` times `double` is the compiler author is figuring, as long as you are going to a `double` in the end anyway, why not use it first? Using `int` times a `double` (cast from the `float`) and then multiplying by a `double` may get you a more accurate result. So it tells you about this opportunity.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Aah it makes sense now! Thanks

Comment: @ProgrammingRage: So an `int` times a `float` by itself does not get the warning, because you are just ending up with a `float`, and the compiler has no reason to think you might later want more precision there. It is just the `int` times `float` times `double` that has the opportunity to widen the arithmetic earlier.

Comment: @EricPostpischil does casting it earlier affect the performance?

Comment: @ProgrammingRage: It could, depending on the machine and circumstances. Probably not much, and possibly zero, depending on the machine and circumstances.